# hacked wordpress - howto get rid of "casino ..."

Tags: wordpress, security

In my wordpress I suddenly do have a low CSS z-index hyperlink to some casino. It only appears left and right to the content due to the low CSS z-index.

How can I find where this code is located?

```
<!-- Enter your scripts here -->            <style>
                .sydney-svg-icon {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 16px;
                    height: 16px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    line-height: 1;
                }
                .team-item .team-social li .sydney-svg-icon {
                    width: 14px;
                }
                .roll-team:not(.style1) .team-item .team-social li .sydney-svg-icon {
                    fill: #fff;
                }
                .team-item .team-social li:hover .sydney-svg-icon {
                    fill: #000;
                }
                .team_hover_edits .team-social li a .sydney-svg-icon {
                    fill: #000;
                }
                .team_hover_edits .team-social li:hover a .sydney-svg-icon {
                    fill: #fff;
                }   
                .single-sydney-projects .entry-thumb {
                    text-align: left;
                }   

            </style>
        <!--buffer start custom--!>
<!--start callback custom--!>
<div style="position:absolute; filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0.003;z-index:8;">
<h3>Keno ziehung wann</h3>

<p> 
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.myhackeddomain.com/electronic-casino-apps-at/">Free Card Games Virtual Casino Austria</a>: Es spielt keine Rolle, auf welche Version des progressiven Cash Splash-Spielautomaten Sie setzen, da beide die gleichen Chancen haben, den Jackpot zu knacken.
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.myhackeddomain.com/vienna-best-casino-odds/">Legal Blackjack In At</a> - Stellen Sie also sicher, dass Sie das Kleingedruckte gründlich lesen, bevor Sie die Angebote und Boni in Anspruch nehmen.
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.myhackeddomain.com/new-casinos-at/">Instant Withdrawal Virtual Casino Austria</a>: Aber für diejenigen unter Ihnen, die ein großes verfügbares Budget haben, Geduld und den Mut, ein wenig zu riskieren, können Sie bis zum 10,000-fachen Ihres Einsatzes gewinnen, wie es Michael im Vera & John Casino getan hat.
    </li>
</ol>
</p>

<h3>Freispiele kaufen online casino</h3>

<p>
    <dl>
  <dt><a href="https://www.myhackeddomain.com/free-slots-vienna-casinos/">Free Casino At 2023</a></dt>
    <dd>Das ist der interessanteste Aspekt, der bei der Überprüfung der von Dunder angebotenen Boni zu berücksichtigen ist.</dd>
  <dt><a href="https://www.myhackeddomain.com/about-online-casino-in-austria-live-dealer-games/">Fruit Gambling Machine Austria</a></dt>
    <dd>Außerdem ist dies Länderabhängig.</dd>
    <dd>Die Eier, die am niedrigsten auszahlen sind blau, grün und weiß gemustert.</dd>
</dl>
</p>

<h3>Wo kann ich online casino spielen</h3>

<p>
<a href="https://www.myhackeddomain.com/best-online-casinos-for-austria/">Bonus Casino Deposit At</a></br>
Dies hängt von jedem einzelnen Casino ab.</br>
<a href="https://www.myhackeddomain.com/blackjack-sites-for-real-money-at/">Austria Popular Casino Documentary Online</a></br>
Während des Spiels musst du den Drachen mit einer Waffe treffen.</br>
<a href="https://www.myhackeddomain.com/how-to-win-money-from-casino-bonuses-and-card-games-in-austria/">Free Virtual Casino In Austria Games 2023</a></br>
</p>



</div>
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #f1f0eb; }
</style>
```

I have found this in mysql dump:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE 'home_links_custom_%'
```

Where can I find this in wordpress admin? I have checked menu items an have not found these entires

update 1:
the casino links are already in the server side rendered response. so no late javascript injection

update 2:

```
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE 'home_links_custom_%';
```

How can I find which code interpretes these "home_links_custom_"?

- official wordpress
- a plugin
- an hacker injected code

In "admin" in my menus, I have not found a menu with the casino links. Does this mean a hacker injected code puts this to the html?

update 3:
I have found the file which renders the links:
/wp-content/themes/sydney/functions.php_bak

I wonder how the attacker managed to get the .php_bak there

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR: I don't think you can solve it in Admin view.

Just some trouble shooting ideas:

Open the infected page in **code view** (STRG+U) and search for some of these Ad strings like "Casino ab":

#### 1. If you can't find them in your source code

the text is most likely **injected via javaScript**

If you can't find it here: at least you know, there must be amalicious script injecting the content.

#### 2. If they are visible in source code

The content was most likely injected in the **database.**

Try installing a "search replace" plugin like [search and replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) – probably not "Better Search and Replace" (the most popular one - can't recommend it for this purpose).

So you can search for the string in a test query and detect in which table it is located.

#### switch theme to a default like "twenty 2X"

This way you can detect whether your **theme was compromised** (or your database or a plugin).
If you still see the injected content – you need to check your database or your plugins.

#### Disable plugins all at once

If you have ftp access got to your wp-content directory and prepend a ".." to your "plugins" folder.
Might cause other conflicts, but if you see the content without ads – it is probably a compromised plugin.

#### Duplicate the infected state

You can use something like duplicator to copy your site to your local server (xamp, mamp etc) to analyze what caused this issue.

#### Rollback

If you don't have any backup/rollback options installed – pretty much any hoster has some kind of backup/rollback function. Otherwise contact your hosting provider's support.

#### Switch to maintenance mode

Put your site offline to prevent harm for your visitors.

Add this to your function php

```
function maintenance_mode() {
 
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_themes' ) || !is_user_logged_in() ) {wp_die('Maintenance.');}
 
}
add_action('get_header', 'maintenance_mode');
```

Good luck!